# What is the use case difference between Process StartInfo.Environment vs EnvironmentVariables?

Tags: .net

I do understand that they are different types (Dictionary<string, string> vs StringDictionary) also other minor implementation differences, but what are the different use cases when use one vs other? ...or is this just a redundancy in StartInfo implementation?

Comment: Redundant.  Environment was added in .NET 4.6, *probably* because they were still hoping in .NETCore 1.0 that they could get rid of obsolete types.  Didn't work out, EnvironmentVariables was added in .NETCore 2.0

Comment: Many thx. In case you are posting this as answer, just the same sentences as in your comment I am going to accept it,